# "... and the cities are fortified and very large" - how would ex-Egyptians see Canaanean cities?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yetziat-mitzrayim, shemot-exodus, archaeology

[Tel Hevron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Rumeida) (the ancient settlement in Hebron) features a fragment of a Middle Bronze Age city wall. The sign cites the verse "*However, the people who inhabit the country are powerful, and the cities are fortified and very large; moreover, we saw the Anakites there.*" [Numbers.13.28](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).
[image]

A frum guide explained that the Hebrew spies saw the huge walls of ancient Bronze Age Hebron and feared the might of the local peoples. However, as I recall, the same generation was said to have built the Egyptian cities of Ramses and Pitom, which were undoubtedly far more technologically advanced.

What are possible ways to reconcile these archeological findings with the scripture?

Comment: I know a dati guide who often guides in the area. I wonder if it's the same person. To the point: Tours, like museums and tourist attractions, aren't always 100% historically and/or archeologically accurate. Guides have no obligation to earn a degree in either field (although some do and I know a few of those). So there's no actual evidence that the spies were afraid of Chevron's walls specifically. Guides often say what they will to make the tour interesting and exciting.

Comment: However, your question is still relevant in general: Why were the spies afraid of Canaanite cities? Given many commentaries on the עין הרע of The spies As well as their motives, it seems likely that they were embellishing at least partly. With that said, we don't fully know what Egypt and Canaan looked like during the time of Bnei Yisrael. Every artistic reconstruction of archeological sites is based on existing data, parallels and the artist's imagination. Were they as tall as the drawing, or even taller? Or shorter? This and other questions don't have really clear answers right now.

Comment: Another point that's worth mentioning is that Yestziat Mitzrayim was likely around the period where the Egyptians would go on periodical military campaigns to stomp the rebellious Canaanites. This went on for generations. From afar, the Canaanites were seen as a nuisance. But some very tough battles were fought in Canaan during these campaigns. Canaanites were no joke, it seems.

Comment: "the same generation was said to have built the Egyptian cities of Ramses and Pitom, which were undoubtedly far more technologically advanced" yes, and they also "feared the might of the local peoples" there too, hence the reason they were slaves.

Comment: Anyway, let's say indeed Pisom and Raamses were more technologically advanced. So? If you're faced with a 50-foot wall, then even if in the past you've seen 100-feet walls, doesn't matter much if you don't have the wherewithal to scale the former.